# setState is updating immediately even after using setTimeOut

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a div with 10 elements, which are to be updated one-by-one with a time delay of say 2secs. Below is the code for the same

```
for(let boxNo=0; boxNo<10; boxNo++){
  setTimeout(() => {
    nodes[boxNo].isMarked = true;
    this.setState({nodes});
    }, (boxNo*200)+boxNo);
  );
}
```

But when i run it, all the elements are updated together. The program just adds a delay add the beginning, and all the elements are updated (isMarked) together. How can I make the code to mark the elements one-by-one?

Comment: 200 ms is fast. Try increasing it to 2000.

Comment: You appear to have an extra parenthesis and semicolon in your code as well. The second to last line.

Comment: Why `+boxNo` is needed in `(boxNo*200)+boxNo`? And `200` => `2000`.

Comment: React will aggregate consecutive `setState`s so that may be having an effect here.

Comment: @JosephD. Tried that. It just increases the delay at the beginning from 200ms to 2000ms and then all the elements are updated together.

Comment: @Antonio +boxNo to add a delay in the beginning(as during initial state boxNo=0 and time delay will be 0*200=0). And regarding 2000ms, tried that as well. It just increases the delay at the beginning from 200ms to 2000ms and then all the elements are updated together.

Comment: @Andy Even I am thinking the same, is there any way to add delays for setState

Comment: You are creating timeout functions independently. Instead create a new time out function after your current one has finished.

Comment: @desikart +boxNo will not be working as you expected. when boxNo is zero, `(0*200)+0 => 0`. So it might be `(boxNo + 1)*200` -> `(0+1)*200 => 200`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're breaking two of the fundamental rules of React:

1. [Don't mutate state directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)

   ```
   for(let boxNo=0; boxNo<10; boxNo++){
     setTimeout(() => {
       nodes[boxNo].isMarked = true; // <==== here
       this.setState({nodes});
       }, (boxNo*200)+boxNo);
     );
   }
   ```
2. If updating state based on existing state, [use the callback form](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) because state updates may be asynchronous (and in any case, in your example, time has passed):

   ```
   for(let boxNo=0; boxNo<10; boxNo++){
     setTimeout(() => {
       nodes[boxNo].isMarked = true;
       this.setState({nodes});       // <==== here
       }, (boxNo*200)+boxNo);
     );
   }
   ```

Instead, see `***` comments and associated code:

```
// **IF** `nodes` is an array
for(let boxNo=0; boxNo<10; boxNo++){
  setTimeout(() => {
    // *** Note using callback form (#2)
    this.setState(({nodes} => {
        // *** *Copy* the parts of state you're going to modify (#1)
        nodes = [...nodes];
        nodes[boxNo] = {...nodes[boxNo], isMarked: true};
        return {nodes};
    });
    }, (boxNo*200)+boxNo);
  );
}
```

that `setState` call can also be written like this at the *(trivial)* expense of creating a temporary object:

```
this.setState(({nodes} => ({
    nodes: Object.assign([], nodes, {[boxNo]: {...nodes[boxNo], isMarked: true}})
});
```

or

```
// **IF** `nodes` is a non-array object
for(let boxNo=0; boxNo<10; boxNo++){
  setTimeout(() => {
    // *** Note using callback form (#2)
    this.setState(({nodes} => {
        // *** *Copy* the parts of state you're going to modify (#1)
        return {
            nodes: {
                ...nodes,
                [boxNo]: {...nodes[boxNo], isMarked: true}
            }
        };
    });
    }, (boxNo*200)+boxNo);
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your option 1 since nodes is an array object, but the problem still exists. All the nodes are updating together. I am unable to visualize it as a path (I want the nodes to update one-by-one with a time delay.)

Comment: @desikart - You'll need to update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Thanks so much. I was passing a shallow copy of nodes in a function because of which the problem occurred. I tried it with deep copy, and it worked. Anyways, thanks for your valuable inputs and time.

Comment: @desikart - Glad that helped! Just to be clear (you probably know this), you don't have to deep copy *everything*, just the things you're going to change. That's why I don't copy any of the other objects that are in `nodes` above other than `nodes[boxNo]`, there's no need. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout is calculating the 200 in your loop first time.

try to increase the time with more milliseconds.

> 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds)

```
    for(let boxNo=0; boxNo<10; boxNo++){
(function(x){
      setTimeout(function(){
        nodes[boxNo].isMarked = true;
        this.setState({nodes});
        }, ((x+1)*3000)+x);}
      )(boxNo);
    }
```

Comment: That's just for reference

Comment: Still the same problem. Now it adds 3secs delay at the beginning and the state of all the elements are updated together.

Comment: Check the answer now. It Might work now. Check for brackets before using it. I'm using my mobile to answer this . that's why?

Comment: Thanks so much. I was passing a shallow copy of nodes in a function because of which the problem occurred. I tried it with deep copy, and it worked. Anyways, thanks for your valuable input and time

Answer (score 0):

This works for fine for me.

```
 (function loop (boxNo) {          
  setTimeout(function () {   
     nodes[boxNo].isMarked = true;
     this.setState({nodes});                
     if (--boxNo) loop(boxNo);    // decrementing i and calling loop function again if i > 0
  },  ((boxNo+1)*2000)+boxNo)
})(10);
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I was passing a shallow copy of nodes in a function because of which the problem occurred. I tried it with deep copy, and it worked. Anyways, thanks for your valuable inputs and time